# Redux - reducer not getting called

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I'm trying to learn Redux. I followed an online tutorial and used their example and it worked fine. Then I made another small test app and it worked fine. Now I'm trying another small test app and I'm stuck on this error and have no idea why.

The app is simply a input box and a button, and when you click the button it adds whatever's in the box to a list that is displayed below.

However, the reducer isn't updating the state. I've looked at the common problems that cause this and can't seem to find those errors in mine, my reducer doesn't change the state and I've bound the dispatch and so on. Maybe I've just mispelled something somewhere (or something small and stupid like that) but I just can't get it working.

So I tried to change it so that it just displays whatever you type in the box below and it STILL doesn't work. Anyone know why the reducer isn't activating?

**index.js** (main)

```js
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import promise from 'redux-promise';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import allReducers from './reducers';
import App from './components/App';

const logger = createLogger();
const store = createStore(
    allReducers,
    applyMiddleware(thunk, promise, logger)
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**App.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import NameList from '../containers/name-list.js'
import Input from '../containers/input.js'

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Input />
    <hr />
    <NameList />
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

**index.js** (action)

```js
export const addName = (name) => {
    return {
        type: 'NAME_ADDED',
        payload: name
    }
};
```

**reducer-add-name.js**

```js
export default function (state = null, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'NAME_ADDED':
            return action.payload;
            break;
    }
    return state;
}
```

**index.js** (reducer combiner)

```js
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import AddNameReducer from './reducer-add-name';


const allReducers = combineReducers({
    nameList: AddNameReducer
});

export default allReducers
```

**input.js**

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {addName} from '../actions/index'

class Input extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <input id='name-input' />
        <button id='add-name-button' onClick={() => addName(document.getElementById('name-input').value)}>Add name</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    nameList: state.nameList
  };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({addName: addName}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(Input);
```

**name-list.js**

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class NameList extends Component {

  getNameList() {
    //This is where I'll loop through this.props.nameList and build the list of elements
    return this.props.nameList;
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>Current list : {this.getNameList()}</div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    nameList: state.nameList
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(NameList);
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Check the console for any errors. Also I can't see your reducer exporting AddNameReducer (which is imported in index.js), but you may have just missed this off the post rather than the real code.

Comment: There are no console errors at any point. And AddNameReducer is just the reducer-add-name.js file, which is a single exported function.

Comment: The connect function in input.js is mapping dispatch methods to props for the Input component. So when the Input component's render function calls addName it would expect to reference this as a prop? (So try this.props.addName)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think your action hasn't been dispatched.

In your **input.js**
On button tag, change

```
onClick={() => addName(document.getElementById('name-input').value)}
```

to

```
onClick={() => this.props.addName(document.getElementById('name-input').value)}
```

Thing is action should be passed through mapDispatchToProps and 'bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)' will wrap your action with 'dispatch', and pass through your component via props 'addName'. (as defined in your mapDispatchToProps)

An action alone is like a bullet (just return object) you will need something to fire it (dispatch)

In your case

```
import {addName} from '../actions/index' <--- a bullet
```

has been declared and your onClick, without dispatch, it would only return a mere object, not dispatching it to reducer.

```
addName() // <--- Just a bullet
```

But

```
this.props.addName() // <--- bullet with a gun
```

is from mapDispatchToProps / bindActionCreators... it has dispatch() wrapped around, that is the one we would use.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was using object destructuring and forgot to add the action to the destructure

Answer (score 4):

Not the OP's question but for people who just searched Google for "reducer not getting called", make sure you call your action creator:

`dispatch(action())`

not

`dispatch(action)`

You have to pass in the action, not the action creator. With `useSelect` in Redux Toolkit I usually don't have parens in the arg so I forgot to put the parents in the call to `dispatch`.

Answer (score 3):

You should combine existing state with the new action payload in reducer-add-name.js instead of just returning the payload i.e.

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {
    todos: [
      ...state,
      {
        action.payload
      }
    ]
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me today.

I forgot to add my new action to my destructured props in React while using the class method

```
const { newAction } = this.props
```